# use syntastic (or any vim checker) on a sagemath

Tags: vim, sage, syntastic

I'm using vim for `.sage` files and I try to have a checker for these files. **syntastic** can handle python verification (with **flake8**) so I wanted to try this.

The first idea I had is to put something like this in my *.vim/filetype.vim* :

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sage    setfiletype sage
```

But, I have some "useful" things in my *.vim/ftplugin/sage.vim* so I don't want to assimilate *.sage* files and *.vim* files.

So, my question is: is it possible for example to just tell syntastic to treat *.sage* files as a *.py* file?

The other problem I may have is that **flake8** won't be happy with the sagemath functions that don't exist in python. Is there something I can do with that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `:h 'syntastic_filetype_map'`

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I was, I hope, just to tired to understand well enough the faq of syntastic..

I put

```
let g:syntastic_sage_checkers = ['python/flake8']
et g:syntastic_sage_flake8_args = '--ignore=F821
```

in my *.vimrc*

the first line, as explained in the syntastic page, tells that "even if the type is sage, I will use flake8, usually used for python files.

the second disable the error **F821** of **flake8**, it is the error for *"undefined name".*
It is usefull because of the sagemath functions that differs from python..

`

Answer (score 0):

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.sage set filetype=sage
```

should be in `~/.vim/ftdetect/sage.vim`.

Comment: why? It's working fine with filetype.vim and all the declaraction of this kind are placed here, whithout any problem. I don't remenber now when I had find this, but it's working.

Comment: 1) because a sentence like "so I don't want to assimilate .sage files and .vim files." shows that you don't understand how it all works. 2) because it is cleaner in many ways than `filetype.vim`.

Comment: According to `:help new-filetype`, both `~/.vim/filetype.vim` and `~/.vim/ftdetect/*.vim` are fine. The latter has the benefit of being composable, but that is only important for plugins, not for a custom configuration. There, it can be nice to have everything in one single file.